# How do I prevent command from splitting output in multiple lines?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a very simple bash script that looks like this:

```
printf '1\n' | myapp > ../values.txt
```

were *myapp* is a bin that asks for a question where I want to answer with "1".

The problem is that the output is pretty wide and *myapp* is actually continuing to print in the next line after a set amount of characters.

Is there a way for me to tell my script that the "output width" is as long as you'd like it to be and don't change lines unless the actual output has a newline character?

I did some research and it seems like the $COLUMNS variable *might be* what I need. But I couldn't make it work.

Comment: How do you tell "myapp is actually continuing to print in the next line"? I don't think `values.txt` has more lines than `myapp` intended it to have originally.

Comment: Don't mistake folded lines for actual linefeeds. The truth is in `wc -l ../values.txt` that returns the actual number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try (Example after 10 char):

```
echo "asjdajsdoiajsodijaosidjaoijsdoaijoasjoadi" | sed -e "s/.\{10\}/&\n/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

How  `yourapp` writes output is it's own decision. You can massage the output (as the other anwer says), but to change the output format you'd have to change `yourapp`.